# How to know if Cache Only DNS server works?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

I have properly configured a Primary DNS server in CentOS 7 and it works fine. I have *tried* to configure a Cache Only DNS server on another machine and I am not sure if it works or not.

Here is my `/etc/named.conf` from the cache only server:

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.1; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.1.0/24; };
        #allow-query-cache      { localhost; 192.168.1.0/24; };
```

This is all I did on the cache DNS server. I start `named` service and enabled it to start on boot.
On client machine in `/etc/resolv.conf` I specified the nameserver as cache dns server IP address.

The problem here is when I ping any machine from client using their hostname, the client machine returns the following error:

```
ping: primarydns.linux.com: Name or service not known
```

Can anyone please help me? I am really not sure when I did wrong on the cache server.

Comment: I guess you are missing the `forwarders {}` option where you specify your upstream DNS servers.

Comment: @Thomas Forwarding is not necessary, though.

Comment: `primarydns.linux.com` is a name which does not exist, which is also what your error message suggests. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do and include relevant dig output?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist as I said I want to configure a caching only DNS server. The `/etc/named.conf` is from the cache server. `primarydns.linux.com` does exist. That is my primary dns server what is authoritative from linux.com domain. I am trying to configure a cache only dns server

Comment: @Paul Ok, `linux.com` is a zone on your own authoritative nameserver? Is there some particular reason why you have a zone by that name? For a normal setup, what appears to be missing is *delegation*, but that will be a problem as you have a zone name that you will not be able to delegate. Either you are trying to achieve something very specific by having a zone that obviously conflicts with already existing domain names (if so, add information on what you are trying to do), or I would say that is fundamentally wrong if you are trying to set things up *normally*.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist my virtual machines are not connected to the internet, so it should not conflict.Again I am doing this for practice. I had one primary DNS server with forward and reverse zone and they work fine. I am ping them using their hostnames. I am trying to setup a cache server, but I am not sure if I did it right?

Comment: @Paul I suspect that you have set it up right for looking up names in the widely used public internet DNS tree. However, your own local `linux.com` zone is not a part of that.  To my knowledge this last comment of yours was the first mention of "doing this for practice" and "not connected to the internet", please elaborate on the actual end goal. Do you want your own totally isolated DNS infrastructure for a lab environment?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Yes, I just want an isolated network for DNS practice.

Comment: @Paul Can you work a description of that overall goal into the question? I'll have a stab at answering it later (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist So I want a cache only DNS server. The `/etc/named.conf` configuration I showed above is all I did on cache dns server. Obviously cache server does not have any forward or reverse zones.

Comment: Without 'forwarders' in place, your cached server is going to try to resolve queries the only way it knows how - by querying the "real" DNS infrastructure.  With a 'forwarders' pointing to that server you have your linux.com domain defined on, that server will sorta simulate the "real" DNS infrastructure for everything except the domains like linux.com you kinda hijacked for your lab which will resolve to your local zones.  Most people think this is a poor idea, even for labs and would suggest using something like linux.local.  Personally, it matters little to me what you do in your lab ;-)

Comment: @BrandonXavier Using forwarders is pretty pointless approach if the goal is learning DNS, though. It'd work as a quick fix, but teaches nothing useful regarding how DNS normally operates.

Comment: @Paul I think there's an element of confusion regarding Serverfault practices at play here. What I'm suggesting is that you edit any clarifications into the *question* (the term used for your original post). The *question* is supposed to stand alone, important information should not be hidden away in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion in the comments for the question suggests that the actual goal is to set up a local, completely isolated, DNS environment for training purposes.

I'll outline the fundamental components needed to mimic how DNS operates on the public Internet inside such an isolated environment.

#### Authoritative side

- Nameserver that is authoritative for your own version of a root (`.`) zone. This root zone should have delegations for any TLDs you use in your environment.
- Nameserver that is authoritative for your own version of some TLD (`com` in your example). The TLD zone should have delegations for any zones that exist below it.
- Nameserver that is authoritative for your own zone (`linux.com` in your example).

While these zones could technically all reside on the same nameserver, you will not be able to observe typical behavior if you set things up that way. To be able to observe relevant behavior you should have three separate nameservers for your example.

#### Recursor side

- One caching recursor nameserver where you have a custom root (`.`) *hint zone* (specifying only the root server in the above environment and its IP).
  If DNSSEC is in use in your training environment, specify a trust anchor for the root (`.`) with the KSK used for your root zone. If DNSSEC is not in use, disable DNSSEC validation.

With this in place, the recursor will be able to operate normally and follow the chain of delegations to any zone that exists in your training environment, just like it would if it was on the public Internet.